# Как настроить автодополнение в nRepl CIDER?

Tags: плагин, autocomplete, редактор, emacs, clojure

Автодополнение в Emacs работает при редактировании кода при включении clojure-mode. Что нужно настроить, чтобы оно было ещё и в nRepl?

Comment: Каком **клиенте** nREPL?

Comment: @D-side а какие клиенты бывают? У меня в Emacs CIDER установлен.

Comment: тьфу, да, CIDER .-.  Ну, это вопрос к гуру emacs, видимо.

Comment: @D-side что-то есть получше этой связки для Clojure?

Comment: Скорее нет, но я ещё недостаточно суров для emacs.